# Is there a way to define css for shadow root element

Tags: html, css, ionic4

[image]

Notice the date is cut off from this image.
If I modify in the console with the following it will show all of the text.

```css
.select-text {
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 16px;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

I can modify the css in the console and it will wrap the text but it won't work when I attempt to implement it in the code.

I've tried adding that .css to global.css and to variable.scss and it still doesn't add the white-space: pre-wrap attribute.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your codes not working :(

Comment: You need to use ::ng-deep selector, I think it still works but it will be deprecated soon ...